# Are questions related to running martial arts classes on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We seem to have determined that training advice is on topic, but what about questions related to the running of your own dojo? I don't mean questions of book keeping or similar, but specific problems that might arise to new instructors? Some examples might include:

- How do I go about hosting an embu (a type of demonstration)?

or

- Does having a waiver really limit my liability?

I don't see this happening too very often, but figured while we're in beta it might be worth considering.

Comment: Good question to consider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think questions about running a dojo (or other martial art center/ gym/ training facility) are on topic.  maybe not the legal ones, but questions of discipline, teaching styles, retaining members, and the like should all be considered on topic.

Comment: As for legal, always put *I am not a lawyer and neither do I play one on TV* disclaimer?  ;)

Comment: I shudder at anything that treads too close to "legal advice"...

Comment: Agreed that this should be on-topic. Any question that requires the ol' "I Am Not A Lawyer" disclaimer should be off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Running the practical side of a dojo is all part of teaching, which I think we all agree is very much on topic. Specific questions like *Does having a waiver really limit my liability?* may be starting to skirt the fringes of being off topic or too localized.

In any case the site is young and I believe we should be slightly more liberal at the start until the site has shaken itself out a little bit.

*I've just taken part of this answer and posted it over on [What are the boundaries for topicality?](https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com/a/41/70)*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the core of the issue is that if the question relates to martial arts instruction (i.e. art forms to mix, teaching methods, psychical training, equipment, etc) would be good. But questions that delve into the business side (i.e. legal issues, retention, location, advertising, etc) would be outside of scope.

Personally I love to hear how people are instructed, learn and the diversity in how training in conducted. Having instructors ask on topic questions that members of this community could answer and improve the quality of instruction would be great benefit.